# WebRTC Broadcasting - Make a Peer Act as a Streaming Server

Tags: webrtc, broadcasting

Can we implement a **mid-scale broadcasting (maybe upto few hundreds)** over WebRTC by using a star topology.

Here a peer can take the role of a streaming server (and even be put in a server kind of setup from where more bandwidth is accessible).

Will this kind of setup not scale pretty well (as the central peer can take advantage of a server infrastructure, if needed); say for 100-200 users or even more?

Can we consider it a viable option than going with a dedicated MCU solution? Or, if you know can you point out its limitations?

Can somebody point me to any implementation code for this?

Answer (score 0):

That would be quite difficult. I *think* that in theory you could pass stream from one peer connection to multiple other ones. That said even if it works, I really doubt it will work on any reasonable scale.

The best way is to use the MCU. You'll get a real star topology.

I can only suggest using our services - AddLive - http://www.addlive.com (usual disclaimer - I work there).